# Crazy comment - no text wrap

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, comments

Whats happened here then?

Mac OS: 10.13.3
Safari: 11.0.3

[image: Comment]

Comment: Safari: why we can't have nice things.

Comment: FWIW, balpha's working on rendering comments without using a table; this is now disabled until a fix is found.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
commit 6055fde149b4f8311234baca9d36f80e34ef80e2
Author: Benjamin Dumke-von der Ehe
Date:   Mon Jan 29 20:56:56 2018 +0100

    Safari is the new IE

-@supports (display: contents) {
+
+/*
+    While `@supports (display: contents)` clearly means
+
+      > only apply this CSS if you support `display: contents`,
+
+    Safari takes this to be more of a suggestion than a strict requirement
+    and applies it anyway, despite *not* supporting `display: contents`.
+
+    So we also use a (negative) feature query to browser-sniff Safari.
+
+    Remember how feature queries were supposed to end the need for these hacks? Yup.
+*/
+
+@supports (display: contents) and (not (-apple-trailing-word: auto)) {
```

Comment: Safari is the new IE... I can't stop laughing oh my goodness

Comment: I did notice the comment issue in Safari earlier but when checking in another browser noticed they also looked odd (not as bad as Safari but not aligned with previous comments) in Android Chrome

Comment: Which I still see now. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjoAv.png

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks, fixing.