# Comment rendering bugged on meta SO in FF50

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, comments

On meta, comments now render as follows under Firefox 50:

[image: meta so comment bug]

The score as well as the upvote arrow and flagging icon is rendered in a separate line above the comment text. It's two `div`s in the dom, so I think I'm seeing the non-table comment rendering Shog is talking about in the screenshot. It looks similar to the bug in [the safari question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362668/1110381) but the comments do wrap correctly, so I don't think it's the same problem.

Answer (score 9):

While Firefox 50 technically isn't a browser we support, the main issue here is that I made the assumption that any browser that supports `display: contents` also supports `display: grid`, which was an incorrect assumption to make – Firefox has been supporting the former for much longer.

Since it's easy to explicitly check for support of *both* values, I'll add that to the next build.