# Comments misaligned when viewed in Luakit on Arch Linux

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, comments

On some Stack Exchange site, the comments aren't in their place:

[image]

As you can see, the comments are not at the positions where they are supposed to be at. (under questions and answers)

I am using Luakit on Arch Linux. Visiting the page from Mozilla Firefox doesn't have the issue.

I also asked some other users, they doesn't have the problem.

I tried hard refresh (Shift+R), that doesn't help.

The problem only happen recently.

<sub>I know my browser isn't [supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161) but...</sub>

Comment: I'd suggest posting a bug report on the browser's support page. This doesn't seem to be an SO / SE issue.

Comment: "I know my browser isn't supported but..." ... I want support for my browser. :P

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Basically like that.

Comment: @Cerbrus So if SE doesn't want to support browser, browser must support SE? ...

Comment: You may need to ask the browser support team to add support for display: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362705/comment-rendering-bugged-on-meta-so-in-ff50

Comment: @user202729: Short answer: Yes. Your browser is outdated. It should update.

Comment: ... Downvote? "This question doesn't show any research effort; it's unclear or not useful"? How?

Comment: @user202729: Voting on meta [is different](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). These votes are probably meant to express disagreement with the question.

Comment: Misleading tooltip. Disagree with... what? They think it's not a bug? They think the browser should not be supported? Anyone?

Comment: Take a look at my first comment. _"This doesn't seem to be an SO / SE issue."_ is a valid reason to downvote a bug report.

Comment: There *has been* a recent change to comment layouts (like: in the last hour), so to all the downvoters I say: play nice!

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362668/crazy-comment-no-text-wrap

Comment: You should see comments in Lynx IT'S JUST AWFUL I TELL YOU AWFUL so I'm going to go back to reading my email in PINE while they work on it.

Comment: Marking this [meta-tag:status-declined], but see the last paragraph in [this answer of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306503/115866).

Comment: @user202729 Consider using emacs for a browser.

Comment: @ʜᴏᴛsʟᴏᴡᴎᴇss I think it's a text editor? ...

Comment: @user202729 emacs is an operating system. the only thing it lack is a decent text editor.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While we don't *technically* support your browser, work is undergoing to revamp some layout stuff including comments. We're testing this pretty thoroughly with all *supported* platforms, but we also like to help make sure we don't break unsupported browsers if not breaking them comes with no additional overhead. We worked *extremely* well on old versions of IE for years after we stopped supporting them, for instance, just because it wasn't too much work to keep compatibility.

***Please don't expect this to be fixed, the issue is in fact your browser***, but this is a useful bug report as it points out a way that we *might* be able to degrade into unsupported land a little more gracefully.

Comment: Just a reminder: [CSS is hard](https://imgur.com/gallery/Q3cUg29)

Comment: Thanks all SE developers! / Side note: Removing the entire block `@supports (display: grid) and (display: contents) and (not (-apple-trailing-word: auto))` seems to work. No idea why. This may break some other browsers, I don't know. / Is there any temporary fix (locally) you know of?

Comment: @user202729 In that case, you can use custom CSS. Just manually revert everything that section does.

Comment: @user202729 In that case it's probably the same [issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362674/115866) that made me add that `-apple-trailing-word` nonsense in the first place. After all, Luakit is using Webkit as well. FWIW, [Webkit marked `display: contents` as "shipped"](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=157477) (which makes the Safari workaround even more annoying, because it means that the next version of Safari won't get the new layout goodness even though it could).